# How do i make so i don't have rely on the C: with my powershell script

Tags: powershell

If I have a code that goes like this

`"C:\Scripts\ScriptMain\Cal.ps1"`

is it possible to remove the C: and make it run directly from the folder?

I want to work on it without having the dir as a limit with where I can place it.

Comment: while relative paths [`.\PathToFile\FileName.ps1`] will work most of the time, it will sometimes glitch when the OS and PoSh disagree on where `.` is. [*grin*] the solution is to get the path the script is in by using the automatic $Var `$PSScriptRoot`. take a look at >>> about_Automatic_Variables - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs — https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Powershell has support for relative paths.

You can call your script as follows: `".\Cal.ps1"`

Comment: it just keeps saying this
{The term '.\Scripts\ScriptMain\Cal.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.}

Comment: What are you entering in your script? '.\Cal.ps1' or '.\Scripts\ScriptMain\Cal.ps1'? If you do the latter and you are already in the .\Scripts\ScriptMain folder, then it will search for your script at: 'C:\Scripts\ScriptMain\Scripts\ScriptMain\Cal.ps1' and obviously not find it.

Comment: i have tried both things with the ( if ($PileInput -eq 1){.\Scripts\ScriptMain\Cal.ps1} )and the 
( if ($PileInput -eq 1){.\Cal.ps1} ) i'm trying to link it to a input with if and the {}.

Comment: If your script works with the full path, substituting that to .\ should work. I have a feeling it won't work with the full path either.